# Parse text to match db records and and transform them into links (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing

I'm looking for a way to parse a text to turn into links the entities of my web app contained within the text. To make it clear, let's take this text as example:

`Stoner rock and stoner metal are two related sub-genres of hard rock and heavy metal respectively, both combining elements of psychedelic rock, blues-rock, traditional heavy metal and doom metal. The genre emerged during the early 1990s and was pioneered foremost by the Californian bands Kyuss and Sleep.`

I'd like to link all the genres, bands and albums that appear on the text (and exist as entities on my web app), like this:

`<a href="/genre/1">Stoner rock</a> and stoner metal are two related sub-genres of hard rock and <a href="/genre/2">heavy metal</a> respectively, both combining elements of psychedelic rock, blues-rock, traditional <a href="/genre/2">heavy metal</a> and <a href="/genre/4">doom metal</a>. The genre emerged during the early 1990s and was pioneered foremost by the Californian bands <a href="/band/1">Kyuss</a> and <a href="/band/2">Sleep</a>.`

I've thought different alternatives, such as:

1. Storing rails code in the database which would output the links (Ugly and insecure),
2. Do a full search on the database before inserting the text and
   a. Find and transform all my entities into links before saving or
   b. Store the entities ids on a separated column, place anchor tags and then on the view, combine each entity id with its anchor tag

I'm not really happy with any of the alternatives, I think should be a smarter way to handle this. Can you suggest a better approach? I'm using Ruby On Rails 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo-Codes:

```
Keywords.find_each do |keyword|
  text.gsub!(keyword, link_to keyword, some_path_for(keyword))
end
```

Depending on how many keywords you have, this task may be quite CPU intensive. Consider storing the text to DB first and have a background worker (like Resque or Delayed::Job) process each test.

Show the original (unlinked) text until it has been processed. I would suggest using two different table fields for the unlinked and linked texts.